# Query optimization

Tags: sql

I have an stored procedure of this format

```
if(condition 1)
begin
(
  -----
  -----
  select into #temp1
  ----
  drop #temp1
)
end
if(condition 2)
begin
(
  -----
  -----
  select into #temp1
  ----
  drop #temp1
)
end
```

now when the above stored procedure is execute it shows me an error
that:

```
"There is already an object named '#temp1' in the database."
```

When I modify the stored procedure like,

```
if(condition 1)
begin
(
  -----
  -----
  select into #temp1
  ----
  drop #temp1
)
end
if(condition 2)
begin
(
  -----
  -----
  select into #temp2
  ----
  drop #temp2
)
end
```

It works good.But I want to optimize this because of creating too many temporary tables.

Can anybody help me on this?

Comment: Can you not do a `insert if not exists into ....`, What sql engine / server are you using ?

Comment: I presume condition 1 and condition 2 aren't mutually exclusive? Do `#temp1` and `#temp2` have the same structure?

Comment: can you confirm whether you are using SQLServer, and if so, which version?

Answer (score 0):

You can drop the table at the start of the procedure.  It's a bit tricky, but you can check for the existence of a temporary table like:

```
if object_id('tempdb..#temp1') is not null
    drop table #temp1
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd create/drop the temp table outside of the conditional statement like this:

```
create table #temp ...

if(condition 1)
begin
(
  -----
  -----
  select into @temp
  ----
)
end
if(condition 2)
begin
(
  -----
  -----
  select into @temp2
  ----
)
end

drop table #temp
```

Assuming your version of SQL Server supports them, and you are aware of the differences in terms of logging and transactional rollback, it might be better to use a table variable. That way you don't have to worry about it not being dropped once it goes out of scope.

Comment: Surely temporary tables should always be dropped at the end of the procedure, anyway?

Comment: yes, but if it's the last thing the procedure does anyway then why write it twice?

Answer (score 0):

You could try adding `TRUNCATE TABLE #temp1` immediately before `if(condition 2)` in the first layout, but [this question and accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2646695/sql-server-temporary-tables-with-truncate-vs-table-variable-with-delete) implies that a table variable will perform better.