# How to delete all the records in a declared table inside a storedprocedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, temp-tables

I am creating a email queue to handle email sending. From that queue I'm taking X number of records and send emails according to the type field of the records.

For that I have declared a table inside the stored procedure. When X number of records are taken I am setting the status of the record in the  **EmailQ table** to processing. But after sending **X number of records which is now inside the declared table has to be deleted**.

For that I can use Delete but there is this **TRUNCATE to delete all the records** in the table. But the declared table has not identified as a Table.

```
WHILE EXISTS ( SELECT * FROM emailQ WHERE Status != 3)
BEGIN
  CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[SendMails]
  DECLARE @Temp TABLE (......)
  --Declare all the necessary variables

  INSERT INTO @Temp SELECT TOP 10
  WITH (UPDLOCK, HOLDLOCK)

  --Update the email queue table status of selected set of records in to the @Temp

  DECLARE  dataSet CURSOR FORWARD_ONLY FOR (SELECT.......  FROM @Temp)
  OPEN dataSet
  FETCH NEXT FROM dataSet INTO...

  WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
  BEGIN
    --send mails acordingly
  END

  CLOSE dataSet
  DEALLOCATE dataSet

  --Update the email queue table status of completed set of records in to the @Temp

  WAITFOR DELAY...
  TRUNCATE @Temp// This is where this Temp table is not identified as a table(It says     "Incorrect sintax... Expecting a table")

 END
```

What is the most appropriate way to delete the records from this declared table.
I also appreciate the comments on my way of handling the mail sending.

Thanks.

Comment: Did you try "DELETE FROM @Temp" ?

Comment: IT works Thanks aarghh.... Do you know why this Truncate is not working on this declared table.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You should do it with delete

```
DELETE FROM @Temp
```

Check related question

[SQL Server, temporary tables with truncate vs table variable with delete](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2646695/sql-server-temporary-tables-with-truncate-vs-table-variable-with-delete)

More on Truncate and Temp Tables

[TRUNCATE TABLE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa260621(v=sql.80).aspx)

[Should I use a #temp table or a @table variable?](https://web.archive.org/web/20140104182318/http://databases.aspfaq.com/database/should-i-use-a-temp-table-or-a-table-variable.html)

**UPDATE:**

Truncate table won't work with declared table variable. You should use #Temp table instead or deleting rows instead of trancating. Check related question for more info.

**UPDATE 2:**

Great answer by Martin Smith

[What's the difference between a temp table and table variable in SQL Server?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/16385/whats-the-difference-between-a-temp-table-and-table-variable-in-sql-server/16386#16386)

Comment: Oh my bad I reeally have to check my eye sight.(carelessness) Thanks a lot hgulyan

Comment: Is it working? TRUNCATE TABLE @Temp shows me incorrect syntax

Comment: You're right, it doesn't work. I think he did it with delete .

Answer (score 0):

create table as bellow..

```
DECLARE @tempTable table(BatchId int, BatchInputOutputType NVARCHAR(128));
```

Use following query to delete temp table

```
DELETE from @tempTable;
```